# Output of op-amp getting as a constant voltage of 500 mV in PROTEUS

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, proteus

Earlier i tried generating a +5V to -5V square wave using an op-amp as an astable multivibrator . The wave had a frequency of 1 kHz. The op-amp was given +Vcc of 5.5V and -VCC of -5.5V. I got the desired square wave at the output. Now i want to generate 0 to 5V square wave using the same circuit. However when I tried simulating the circuit taking -Vcc as 0V im getting a constant voltage of 500mV. Can you please help me to troubleshoot the circuit. The op-amp I have used is an LM324.

[image]

Comment: Your opamp is trying its hardest to swing low, but the lowest it can go is 500mV (a little above the negative rail). At that point the junction of R1/R2 is about 250mV, so the opamp neg input is still higher than its pos input so the opamp is forever stuck low. In your original design the opamp was free to swing all the way down to -4.5V, and R1/R2 would then set the pos input to about -2.2V, allowing the opamp to flip when C1 voltage reached -2.2V.

Comment: Can you suggest a circuit employing op-amp i can use to get a 0 to +5V pulsating DC waveform at 1KHz? if not, please suggest me the sources which i could use to figure out the connections for op-amp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a resistor to the junction of R1/R2 to bias it away from GND.

For a square wave you'd want it (roughly) half of Vcc. Not exactly because the op-amp output does not swing as close to the positive rail as it does to GND.

Eg:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9yPy7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: I Tried simulating the circuit you've given. However i am getting a constant 5V DC signal at the output instead of pulsating square wave of 0 to +5V at  1KHz. Can you guide me where i coudve made a mistake. I added a 10V DC source at the R1/R2 Junction through a 100k ohm resistor and changed the values of R1 and R2 as 100K ohm as well.

Comment: Either reduce the 10V source or increase the 100k resistor that is connected to it.

Comment: To get some intuition on this try calculating the threshold at which the output switches.

Comment: A real LM324 output can only swing from its negative rail to within 1.5V of its pos rail so should only be able to reach 3.5V max in your case. The fact that the simulation yields 5V under any circumstance is suspect. (Are you sure you didn't short the opamp output to 5V in your schematic?) Since the output swing is only 0 to 3.5V the R2/R3 ratio should be adjusted to half that, about 1.9V. Can do this by making R3 = 62K. If you make R4 = 62K too then the circuit should work and be pretty close to 1kHz. If you really need a full 5V swing you need to use a rail-to-rail opamp (e.g. LMV324)